# A problem in returning a table with Null On it

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want my function to return a A table with some values

I must fix something in the update but i don't know what 
this is the function FngetTableH BELOW

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FnGetTableH] 
 (
  @Date DateTime 
  )
  RETURNS  @Listeab_ Table(CLOSING_PRICE money,IdValeur int)
 AS
  BEGIN

    Insert @Listeab_
   (          CLOSING_PRICE ,IdValeur)

     select Distinct 0 , IdValeur
     From Historique



     Update @Listeab_
       Set CLOSING_PRICE = (Select  CLOSING_PRICE
       from Historique H
      inner join (Select MAX(@Date) As DATEDU,IdValeur FROM Historique
  where 
     DATE_NEGO<= @Date 
       group by IdValeur ) L2
       on 
  H.DATE_NEGO=L2.DATEDU
     and
  H.IdValeur=L2.IdValeur
       )
  return 
 END
```

when i Execute this code

```
declare @Date date = '10/09/2013'

---select*from FnGetTableH(@Date)
select  C.IdClient,H.IdValeur,C.RaisonSocial,SUM( case I.sens 
                                                   WHEN 'c' then  + I.Qantite
                                                   WHEN'd' then  - I.Qantite
                                                  END) as 'Solde', H.closing_price
from Imputations I
Inner join FnGetTableH(@Date) H
on H.IdValeur=I.IdValeur 
Inner join Clients C
on C.IdClient=I.IdClient
where I.DateImputation=@Date    
group by C.IdClient,RaisonSocial,H.closing_price,H.IdValeur
Order by IdClient asc
```

i get

Msg 512, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 4
La sous-requête a retourné plusieurs valeurs. Cela n'est pas autorisé quand la sous-requête suit =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quand elle est utilisée en tant qu'expression.
L'instruction a été arrêtée.

Comment: Please show  code of the `FnGetTableH` TVF.

Comment: it is the first code my friend

Comment: In that case is the issue is that you have a select query before the update?

Comment: can you show the full "create function" code of FnGetTableH so we can see the signature

Comment: i just did it  though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your innermost query I think MAX(@Date) should be MAX(DATE_NEGO), which might explain why the closing price query is returning multiple results.

There is still the possibility of multiple results, so you might need to account for that You could select max(closing_price) if it doesn't matter which, though I suspect it might, in which case you need to do some ordering to select the correct price to use.

EDIT: Try this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FnGetTableH]
(
    @Date DATETIME
)
RETURNS @Listeab_ TABLE
(
    CLOSING_PRICE MONEY,
    IdValeur INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH prices AS
    (
        SELECT IdValeur,
            CLOSING_PRICE,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IdValuer ORDER BY DATE_NEGO DESC) rn
        FROM Historique
        WHERE DATE_NEGO <= @Date
    )
    INSERT @Listeab_(CLOSING_PRICE, IdValeur)
    SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(p.CLOSING_PRICE, 0),
        h.IdValeur
    FROM Historique h
    LEFT OUTER JOIN prices p ON h.IdValeur = p.IdValeur
        AND p.rn = 1
        RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: not its not the case ive tried it but it gave le the same problem

Comment: Pretty sure it should be MAX(DATE_NEGO), MAX(@date) is always going to return the same value. This means you still have multiple qualifying rows, so you need to do TOP 1, and add an ORDER BY before the last bracket. Order by an identity column (descending) if one is available, to pick the most recently inserted row

Comment: it dont get the error msg but it gave me the same closing price to all clients

Comment: so the problem now is i dont know how but it touche the Solde column idk why

Comment: I think my code might have returned duplicates (hard to test without actual tables to hand!). I have added a distinct which should solve that

Answer (score 0):

your query "Select CLOSING_PRICE from Historique H inner..." may be returning more than 1 value.

Comment: where exactly ?,

Comment: Could you give more information about the tables that are used in the view that you created? I cant help you to find out what your table should return, if I dont know what the table looks like/what the columns are.

Answer (score 0):

Use top to select 1 record. May be it will solve your error.

```
select Distinct 0 , IdValeur
From Historique
Update @Listeab_
Set CLOSING_PRICE = (Select  Top 1 CLOSING_PRICE
from Historique H
inner join (Select MAX(@Date) As DATEDU,IdValeur FROM Historique
where 
DATE_NEGO<= @Date 
group by IdValeur ) L2
on 
H.DATE_NEGO=L2.DATEDU and H.IdValeur=L2.IdValeur
)
```

Comment: It gaved me the same closing price in all the output

Comment: it didnt gave me the Error though

Comment: Your error is not clear. Kindly repost error part only.